# SQL - Query to find average of sub category

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLE1:

```
SUBJECTS  TYPE    COST
--------- ------- ----
Subject 1 Math      12
Subject 2 English   13
Subject 3 Math      15
Subject 4 Math      13
Subject 5 English   14
```

I'm trying to calculate the average cost for the "type" of each subject. 
So for subject 1, the query output should be

```
Subject 1, Math, 12, 13.33
```

The last is 13.33 because the average for all math "types" are ([12 + 15 + 13] / 3)

So far I have this:

```
SELECT Subjects, Type, Cost,
(SELECT AVG(Cost) FROM TABLE1)
FROM TABLE1;
```

Am I supposed to do an inner join here or a group by "type" in the select avg query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this using joins:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.avg_cost
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Type, AVG(Cost) AS avg_cost
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY Type
) t2
    ON t1.Type = t2.Type
```

And if you are feeling more adventurous, you can try using `AVG()` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT t.*,
       AVG(t.cost) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Type) avg_cost
FROM TABLE1 t
```

Comment: Analytic functions were invented PRECISELY for the purpose of avoiding (expensive!) joins for this kind of problem. On a separate note, `select *, something_else` is a common beginner mistake; * must be qualified with the table name.

Comment: `common beginner mistake` ... LOL, because that syntax is completely valid on SQL Server and some other RDBMS.  This is most likely a homework question designed to teach joining.

Comment: Both answers are so helpful! Thank you all

Comment: In my class, students will be learning window functions before they learn `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did some research at Columbia about 15 years ago.  Wish you had existed back then :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a self join using analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.*,
       AVG( cost ) OVER ( PARTITION BY type ) As avg_cost
FROM   table1 t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.s1 SUBJECTS, x.t1 TYPE,Avg(c2) aVG_COST 
FROM 
(SELECT a.subjects s1,a.types t1,a.cost c1 ,b.subjects s2,b.types t2,b.cost c2 
FROM TABLE1 a,TABLE1 b
WHERE a.types=b.types ) x 
GROUP BY x.s1,x.t1 ORDER BY X.S1;
```